# How to extract raster class values from a multi polygon shapefile in QGIS

Tags: qgis, raster, shapefile, spatial-statistics

I'm trying to perform a laborious task to get the class values of a raste overlaid on a multi-part shapefile.

I have a raster with values rated from 0 to 8 for a Main Basin. I also have a shapefile with 3 sub-basins of this main basin.

I would like to calculate the value of the raster classes according to the overlay sub-basin.

For example:
shapefile sub-basins: A; B and C.
Raster class: 0 to 8

For class 0 what is the area value for sub-basin A?

[image]

[image]

[image]

In QGIS I know there is `r.report`, however it only does this for a mono-part shapefile (one polygon).

Would there be any tool in qgis that would do this for multiple polygons?

Comment: Try zonal histogram

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Zonal histogram then transpose the output using for example excel or python pandas:

Zonal histogram output, the output raster categories become columns:
[image]

Export to csv and transpose:

```
import pandas as pd
csvfile = r'/home/bera/Desktop/tempgis/output_zonal_hist.csv' #Change to the exported output from Zonal histogram
subbasin_id_field = 'subbasin' #Name of your subbasin id field

df = pd.read_csv(csvfile)
df2 = df.set_index(subbasin_id_field).transpose()
df2.index.name='rasterval'
df2.to_csv(r'/home/bera/Desktop/tempgis/output_zonal_hist_transposed.csv')
```

[image]