# Using buffers in Point Sampling Tool

Tags: qgis, raster, vector, buffer

I have 50m (shape file) buffers around (shape file) data points. I have another layer with the raster of the vegetation (indicated by different colours) in that land. I can easily extract the raster data of the data points using the Point Sampling Tool, but I wanted to find out the percentage of vegetation types within each buffer, using the raster layer.

The drop down menu in the Point Sampling Tool for 'layer containing sampling points' doesn't let me choose the buffer layer. Is there a different tool/method I should use?

[image: Image of buffer and raster layer]

Comment: If you want to and have access to geopandas and rasterstats, this is exactly what you want: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/408583/zonal-histogram-python/408585#408585

Comment: Or skip **geo**pandas and rasterstats and try: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/399561/how-to-extract-raster-class-values-from-a-multi-polygon-shapefile-in-qgis/400678#400678

Comment: Zonal histogram works perfectly! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I will convert the raster file to polygon file and I will use intercept within buffer circles and polygons to calculate each percentage. Shapes must be in projected coordinates.